# Trying to write a loop to print out labels

Tags: vb.net, foreach, printing, do-while

**My code gets all the data for a job then prints out the pallet labels for that job. Right now it just goes through the For each statement and prints out the first label. I'm thinking maybe I need a Do while loop, but am not sure.**

```
Private Sub PrintDocument2_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument2.PrintPage

    Dim JobNum = CInt(getJobNumSTR)
    Dim AssemblyText = "Assembly#"
    Dim PalletQtyText = "Pallet Qty"
    Dim Cup_Part As String
    Dim Serial As String
    Dim Cup_Mfg_Date As String
    Dim Pallet As String
    Dim PalletQty As String
    Dim sqlcon As String = My.Settings.New_Assembly_AccessConnectionString

    Dim rh As Integer
    rh = 0
    Dim BC2 As String

    Using con = New SqlConnection(sqlcon)

        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        Dim sql = "SELECT j.assembly#, p.Serial, p.Cup_Mfg_Date, p.job, p.Pallet, sum(count(p.serial)) over (partition by pallet) as PalletAmount " & _
                  " FROM new_assembly_Access.dbo.tbl_pallet p inner join new_assembly_access.dbo.tbl_job j on j.job# = p.job where p.job = @JobNum " & _
                  " group by j.assembly#, p.Serial, p.Cup_Mfg_Date, p.job, p.Pallet"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobNum", JobNum)
        Dim ds As New DataSet

        con.Open()

        da.Fill(ds, "data")
        Cup_Part = ds.Tables("data").Rows(0).Item("Assembly#")
        Pallet = ds.Tables("data").Rows(0).Item("Pallet")
        PalletQty = ds.Tables("data").Rows(0).Item("PalletAmount")
        Serial = ds.Tables("Data").Rows(0).Item("Serial")
        Cup_Mfg_Date = ds.Tables("Data").Rows(0).Item("Cup_Mfg_Date")

        con.Close()

        BC2 = "*" & Cup_Mfg_Date & Serial & "*"

        Dim BC As New STROKESCRIBECLSLib.StrokeScribeClass
        BC.Alphabet = CODE128
        BC.Text = Cup_Part

        Dim QtyBC As New STROKESCRIBECLSLib.StrokeScribeClass
        QtyBC.Alphabet = CODE128
        QtyBC.Text = PalletQty

        Dim BCW As Integer = BC.BitmapW
        Dim BCH As Integer = BCW / 4

        Dim BCWQ As Integer = QtyBC.BitmapW
        Dim BCHQ As Integer = BCWQ / 4

        Dim olepicture As stdole.StdPicture
        olepicture = BC.GetPictureHandle(BMP, BCW, 34)

        Dim olepictureQty As stdole.StdPicture
        olepictureQty = QtyBC.GetPictureHandle(BMP, BCWQ, 34)

        Dim HLabelFont As System.Drawing.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular)
        Dim LabelFont As System.Drawing.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular)
        Dim LabelFont25 As System.Drawing.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular)
        Dim LabelBold As System.Drawing.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
        Dim PalletFont As System.Drawing.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Bold)
        Dim MyPen As New Pen(Color.Black, 3)

        Using HLabelFont
            e.Graphics.DrawString(AssemblyText, HLabelFont, Brushes.Black, 20, 20)
            e.Graphics.DrawString("PalletQty:", HLabelFont, Brushes.Black, 235, 65)

        End Using

        Using LabelBold
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Cup", LabelBold, Brushes.Black, 20, 52)
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Date", LabelBold, Brushes.Black, 20, 65)
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Serial #", LabelBold, Brushes.Black, 70, 65)
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Pallet #:", LabelBold, Brushes.Black, 320, 130)
        End Using

        Using PalletFont
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Pallet, PalletFont, Brushes.Black, 290, 155)
        End Using

        If PalletQty <= 16 Then

            For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
                Serial = row("Serial")
                Cup_Mfg_Date = row("Cup_Mfg_Date")

                'Using LabelFont
                e.Graphics.DrawString(Cup_Mfg_Date, LabelFont, Brushes.Black, 20, (80 + rh))
                e.Graphics.DrawString(Serial, LabelFont, Brushes.Black, 70, (80 + rh))

                Dim LongBC As New STROKESCRIBECLSLib.StrokeScribeClass
                LongBC.Alphabet = CODE128
                LongBC.Text = Cup_Mfg_Date & "Z" & Serial
                LongBC.ShowText = False

                Dim BCWL As Integer = LongBC.BitmapW
                Dim BCHL As Integer = BCWL / 10
                Dim olepictureLong As stdole.StdPicture
                olepictureLong = LongBC.GetPictureHandle(BMP, BCWL, BCHL)
                Dim imgl As Image
                imgl = Image.FromHbitmap(olepictureLong.Handle)
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(imgl, 140, (80 + rh))

                rh = rh + 25
            Next
        Else
            For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables("Data").Rows
                Serial = row("Serial")
                Cup_Mfg_Date = row("Cup_Mfg_Date")

                e.Graphics.DrawString(Cup_Mfg_Date, LabelFont25, Brushes.Black, 20, (80 + rh))
                e.Graphics.DrawString(Serial, LabelFont25, Brushes.Black, 70, (80 + rh))


                Dim LongBC As New STROKESCRIBECLSLib.StrokeScribeClass
                LongBC.Alphabet = CODE128
                LongBC.Text = Cup_Mfg_Date & "Z" & Serial
                LongBC.ShowText = False

                Dim BCWL As Integer = LongBC.BitmapW
                Dim BCHL As Integer = BCWL / 16
                Dim olepictureLong As stdole.StdPicture
                olepictureLong = LongBC.GetPictureHandle(BMP, BCWL, BCHL)
                Dim imgl As Image
                imgl = Image.FromHbitmap(olepictureLong.Handle)
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(imgl, 140, (80 + rh))

                rh = rh + 16

            Next
        End If

        Dim img As Image
        img = Image.FromHbitmap(olepicture.Handle)
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 90, 20)

        Dim QtyImg As Image
        QtyImg = Image.FromHbitmap(olepictureQty.Handle)
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(QtyImg, 315, 60)

       End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a debugging issue.  Put a stop mark in the code and run it, when it stops, step through the lines one by one examining the values. Do favor For-Loops instead of For-Each when printing because if you have more than one page, you will have to set the `e.HasMorePages = True` in order to call the same code again on the next page.  Some of your variables need to be scoped outside the Print event in order to work in that scenario.

Comment: Well, a single job has multiple pallets. So far my program only prints out the first one. I need it to do this for every pallet number.

Comment: @LarsTech It doesnt error out. it prints out the first label just fine.

Comment: I didn't say anything about an error.  You said it won't loop to the next label.  Debug it to find out why.

Comment: I stepped though it and it goes through all the Serial numbers on each pallet but when it prints, its just the first page. @LarsTech did you say I need to put in e.HasMorePages = True somewhere ?

Comment: See [Printing multiple pages using PrintDocument and HasMorePages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40918621/719186) as a generic example.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try:

```
LongBC.Text = row("Cup_Mfg_Date").ToString.Trim() & "Z" & row("Serial").ToString.Trim()
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the question was about.

Comment: i added a row counter to each loop of the for each statement then told it to break if the row number hit the desired number on each label. then put:  If rownum < ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count Then
                e.HasMorePages = True
            Else
                e.HasMorePages = False
            End If  but its resetting my row count each time to zero

Comment: @ScottSlagle Your comment doesn't seem to be addressed to this answer.  If you have updated code, edit your question with the added information.