# Print data from several lists to several pages through PrintPage in C#

Tags: c#

I have to print the data and results of my application through the PrintPage event. The problem is that I have the data and results to print on List  elements, my first group of List  is printed correctly through a While cycle; but when I add another While to print another group, this starts printing on the same pages printed above, not over writing the pages, but, which starts the next printing on the margins left in the first. Annex fragment of my code.

```
void PrintDocument1PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        owner = (MainForm)this.Owner;
        pcombo = owner.stadoCarga.pcombo;
        printDocument1.PrintController.IsPreview.ToString();
        printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 60;
        printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 60;
        printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 240;
        printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 60;
        Font fte = new Font("verdana", 11, FontStyle.Regular);
        Font ftti = new Font("verdana", 11, FontStyle.Bold);
        Font ft1 = new Font("verdana", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
        Font Fgr = new Font("Impact", 22);
        SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

        Single xPos = e.MarginBounds.Left;
        Single yPos = 220; //e.MarginBounds.Top;
        Single hight = e.MarginBounds.Height;
        Single incLine = 25;

        int printHeight;
        printHeight = e.MarginBounds.Height - printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom -
            printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top;

        int r = 0;
        frmDiagr MSCh = new frmDiagr();
        frmInfo picLogo = new frmInfo();

        LineasPagina = Convert.ToInt32(printHeight / fte.GetHeight(e.Graphics));

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(picLogo.picLogo.Image, 60, 50);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("ADIMA v2.0 Pro", Fgr, Brushes.Green, 230, 50);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Análisis y Diseño de Muros de Mampostería", ftti, Brushes.Green, 230, 87);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Proyecto.:", ft1, Brushes.Black, 60, 120);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(owner.datos.DatosInfo[0], ft1, Brushes.Black, 140, 120);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Cliente.:", ft1, Brushes.Black, 510, 120);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(owner.datos.DatosInfo[1], ft1, Brushes.Black, 575, 120);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Ingeniero.:", ft1, Brushes.Black, 60, 140);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(owner.datos.DatosInfo[2], ft1, Brushes.Black, 140, 140);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Codigo.:", ft1, Brushes.Black, 510, 140);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(owner.datos.DatosInfo[4], ft1, Brushes.Black, 575, 140);
        //  e.Graphics.DrawString("___________________________________________________________________", fte, Brushes.Black, 50, 180)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("DATOS PARA EL DISEÑO", ftti, Brushes.Black, 60, 170);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("- REFUERZOS UNIFORME DE LA SECCION DE MURO", ftti, Brushes.Black, 295, 170);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("MURO No.", fte, Brushes.Black, 60, 210);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("LONG.(m)", fte, Brushes.Black, 170, 210);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("ESP.(m)", fte, Brushes.Black, 270, 210);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("ALT(m)", fte, Brushes.Black, 360, 210);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("f'm(kg/c2)", fte, Brushes.Black, 440, 210);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Em(kg/c2)", fte, Brushes.Black, 540, 210);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Ev(kg/c2)", fte, Brushes.Black, 640, 210);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("PV(to/m3)", fte, Brushes.Black, 740, 210);

        int stop = contador + LineasPagina;// Contador mas cantidad de lineas por pagina
        if(stop > ak.Count){
            stop = ak.Count;
        }
        while (contador < stop) {
            int k = Convert.ToInt32(ak[contador]);
            r = Convert.ToInt32(ak[contador])+1;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(""+r, fte, Brushes.Black, 80, yPos + incLine);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(muroToDiseno[k].ToString(), fte, Brushes.Black, 180, yPos + incLine);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(owner.datosDibujo.espMuro[k].ToString(), fte, Brushes.Black, 280, yPos + incLine);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(owner.datos.Datos[3], fte, Brushes.Black, 370, yPos + incLine);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(owner.datos.Datos[7], fte, Brushes.Black, 460, yPos + incLine);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(owner.datos.Datos[8], fte, Brushes.Black, 550, yPos + incLine);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(txtEsfEv.Text, fte, Brushes.Black, 650, yPos + incLine);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(owner.datos.Datos[12], fte, Brushes.Black, 750, yPos + incLine);
            incLine += 25;
            contador++;
        }
        PaginaNumero += 1;
        e.HasMorePages = contador < ak.Count;
        // Hasta Aqui se Imprime Correctamente....

        int stopC = count + LineasPagina;// Contador mas cantidad de lineas por pagina
        if(stopC > ak.Count){
            stopC = ak.Count;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < sumaFactorizada.Count; i++) {
            while(count < stopC){
                int k = Convert.ToInt32(ak[count]);
                r = Convert.ToInt32(ak[count])+1;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(""+r, fte, Brushes.Black, 80, yPos + incLine);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(Math.Round(sumaFactorizada[i][k],3).ToString(), fte, Brushes.Black, 180, yPos + incLine);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(EQFactorizada[i][k].ToString(), fte, Brushes.Black, 260, yPos + incLine);
                incLine += 25;
                count++;
            }
            PaginaNumero += 1;
            e.HasMorePages = count < ak.Count;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The title of your question should be in English.  You should be checking if you are hitting the bottom of the page from within your While-Loops.  That's also where you should be setting the HasMorePages value.  When HasMorePages is true, this entire method will run again, so your code should be aware of that.  It isn't.

Comment: I place my e.HasMorePages after finishing my While loop but it doesn't seem to make favorable change.

Comment: Think this through.  Your while-loop keeps printing things down the page, but you aren't checking if the line you are printing is actually on the page.  Here is an example in VB.Net, but you should be able to follow the logic: [Printing multiple pages using PrintDocument and HasMorePages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40918621/719186).  Your for-loop is problematic, too, because when HasMorePages is true, it will call this method again, and your entire for-loop runs again because "i" is always starting at zero.