# Receipt has overlapping text in Print Document

Tags: c#, .net, printdocument

I am creating a print receipt in my POS project and attach picture of the output

[image: receipt]

my problem here is the overlapping of description, qty, price, amount.
How to show the qty and price and amount in the next line from this code?

```
e.Graphics.DrawString("Description" , new Font("trebuchet ms", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(0, 260));
e.Graphics.DrawString("Qty" , new Font("trebuchet ms", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(120, 260));
//e.Graphics.DrawString("UM" , new Font("trebuchet ms", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(190, 190));
e.Graphics.DrawString("Price", new Font("trebuchet ms", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(155, 260));          
e.Graphics.DrawString("Amount" , new Font("trebuchet ms", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(205, 260));
e.Graphics.DrawString("-------------------------------------------", new Font("trebuchet ms", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(0, 275));

int yPos = 300;

foreach (var i in TempVal)
{
  e.Graphics.DrawString(i.Particular + " (" + i.UM + ")", new Font("trebuchet ms", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(0, yPos));
  e.Graphics.DrawString(i.Qty, new Font("trebuchet ms", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(120, yPos));
  //e.Graphics.DrawString(i.UM, new Font("trebuchet ms", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(190, yPos));
  e.Graphics.DrawString(i.Price +".00", new Font("trebuchet ms", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(155, yPos));
  e.Graphics.DrawString(i.Total + ".00", new Font("trebuchet ms", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(205, yPos));

  yPos = yPos + 20;
}

e.Graphics.DrawString("-------------------------------------------", new Font("trebuchet ms", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(0, yPos));
e.Graphics.DrawString("Total Amount:                   Php " + label3.Text.Trim(), new Font("trebuchet ms", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(0, yPos+20));
e.Graphics.DrawString("-------------------------------------------", new Font("trebuchet ms", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(0, yPos+35));
e.Graphics.DrawString("Cash Tendered:                 Php " + label4.Text.Trim(), new Font("trebuchet ms", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(0, yPos + 55));
e.Graphics.DrawString("Change:                            Php " + lblTotal.Text.Trim(), new Font("trebuchet ms", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(0, yPos + 75));
e.Graphics.DrawString("-------------------------------------------", new Font("trebuchet ms", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(0, yPos+95));
```

Comment: Hi ZniperpH, have you tired using a newline(\n) or tab (\t)

Comment: Your code prints fine.  Problem is somewhere else.  It looks like your text is too long and overlapping the other "columns".

Comment: unrelated, but for better readability you might consider using something like `var font = new Font("trebuchet ms", 10, FontStyle.Regular);` and then use only this variable as argument for your many `DrawString` calls.

Comment: @rizu, tried newline and measure string but nothing happen

Comment: @LarsTech, yes that is my problem, i want to know if the length of the text is long, the other columns will send to next line, im stuck for almost an hour searching solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will “show the qty and price and amount in the next line” as you asked:

```
using (var f = new Font("trebuchet ms", 10, FontStyle.Regular))
{
    int yPos = 300;
    foreach (var v in TempVal)
    {
      e.Graphics.DrawString(v.Particular + " (" + v.UM + ")", f, Brushes.Black, new Point(0, yPos));
      yPos += 20;

      e.Graphics.DrawString(v.Qty, f, Brushes.Black, new Point(120, yPos));
      e.Graphics.DrawString(v.Price +".00", f, Brushes.Black, new Point(155, yPos));
      e.Graphics.DrawString(v.Total + ".00", f, Brushes.Black, new Point(205, yPos));
      yPos += 20;
    }
}
```

Be aware this only works if `TempVal` is guaranteed to have so few records that they will all fit on one page. If there can be enough records to require more pages, you will have to calculate how many rows will fit on a page and [split your output onto multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40872946/).