# C# Page Printing : issue when there is more than one page

Tags: c#, printing

Good day,

I'm not very familiar with C# , so please bear with me if my question might sound silly.

I'm trying to understand how the page printer works so I wrote a very basic example in which I was aiming at printing out numbers from 0 to 99 on as many pages as necessary. Unfortunately, my attempts so far have not been very successful because it requires me to print an infinite number of pages, as if it were an endless loop.

If I do the same exercise with only 10 iterations (0 to 9), this works like a charm.

Do you have any idea what I might have missed at this stage?

Many thanks for your help and best wishes.

```
public void printDemo()
{
  this.m_Print_Document.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_Print_Page);
  this.m_Print_Document.Print();
}

private void pd_Print_Page(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs pEvent)
{
  float l_Position_Y = 1;    
  float l_Page_Height = pEvent.MarginBounds.Height;
  Graphics g = pEvent.Graphics;
  SolidBrush brush = null;
  Font font1 = null;

  font1 = new Font("Arial", 9);  
  brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);    
    
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
      if (l_Position_Y + 20 < l_Page_Height)
      {
        g.DrawString("Text" + i, font1, brush, 50, l_Position_Y);
        Convert.ToInt32(l_Position_Y), 100, 20);
        l_Position_Y = l_Position_Y + 20;
      }
      else
      {
        pEvent.HasMorePages = true;
        // reset position of variable l_Position_Y
        l_Position_Y = 1;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Every time there is a new page, `pd_Print_Page` runs again.  Which means your loop starts over from the beginning.  You have to declare `i` variable outside that loop and set it to 0 at the beginning of the print job.  See this VB.Net example for the logic: [Printing multiple pages using PrintDocument and HasMorePages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40918621/719186)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the current state of the larger print job somewhere outside of the `PrintPage()` function:

```
public void printDemo()
{
    this.m_Print_Document.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_Print_Page);
    //initialize state for the print job
    currentPosition = 0;
    this.m_Print_Document.Print();
}

// state data for entire print job
int currentPosition;

private void pd_Print_Page(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs pEvent)
{
    float l_Position_Y = 1;    
    float l_Page_Height = pEvent.MarginBounds.Height;
    Graphics g = pEvent.Graphics;
    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 9);
   
    // use the state from the job, rather than from the specific page
    while(l_Position_Y + 20 < l_Page_Height && currentPostion++ < 100)
    {
        g.DrawString($"Text {currentPosition}", font1, brush, 50, l_Position_Y);
        Convert.ToInt32(l_Position_Y), 100, 20);
        l_Position_Y = l_Position_Y + 20;            
    }
    e.HasMorePages =  (currentPostion < 100);
}
```